# Nhibernate Disable Second Level Cache with Fluent - Disable Fake Cache also

Tags: c#, caching, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

```
var config =
            Fluently
                .Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                                            .IsolationLevel(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
                                            .ConnectionString(connectionString)
                                            .DefaultSchema(defaultSchema)
                                            .FormatSql())
                                            .ExposeConfiguration
                                            (
                                                c => c.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", sessionContext)
                                            );

        if (secondLevelCacheSettings.UseSecondLevelCache)
        {
            if (secondLevelCacheSettings.CacheType == SecondLevelCacheSettings.SecondLevelCacheType.Memcached)
            {
                config.Cache(c => c.ProviderClass<MemCacheProvider>().UseQueryCache())
                    .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty("expiration",
                                                            secondLevelCacheSettings.CacheExpirationMinutes.ToString()));
            }
            if (secondLevelCacheSettings.CacheType == SecondLevelCacheSettings.SecondLevelCacheType.HashTable)
            {
                config.Cache(c => c.ProviderClass<HashtableCacheProvider>().UseQueryCache());
            }
        }
```

When I don't want to use second level cache, i want to completely disable it. Seems the default configuration is using FakeCache. How do I disable FakeCache also?

Also in the logs I see,

> 09-04 14:14:02,088 WARN  Second-level cache is enabled in a class, but no cache provider was selected. Fake cache used. - [4] NHibernate.Cache.NoCacheProvider [(null)]

Seems second level cache is enabled by default even though we did not configure it. what is the cleaner way to disable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
config.Cache(x => x.Not.UseSecondLevelCache());
```

solved my problem. It removed all logs and unnecessary cpu cycles. This is via fluent. If you are using configuration following configuration may be needed.

```
<property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">
  false
</property>
```

Comment: Have deleted this config record, accidentally. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would say it this way: Do not worry about `FakeCache` and `NoCacheProvider`. It is just an implementation of the:

#### [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)

> **Description**
>
> Instead of using a **null** reference to convey absence of an object *(for instance, a non-existent customer)*, one uses an **object** which **implements the expected interface**, BUT **whose method body is empty**. The advantage of this approach over a working default implementation is that a Null Object is very predictable and has no side effects: it does nothing.

These are few lines of [FakeCache](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/master/src/NHibernate/Cache/FakeCache.cs):

```
public class FakeCache : ICache
{
    public FakeCache(string regionName)
    {
        RegionName = regionName;
    }

    public object Get(object key)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void Put(object key, object value)
    {
    }

    public void Remove(object key)
    {
    }
    ...
```

So, this is only NHibernate built-in way how to handle situations, when query or second level caches are turned on, but no Provider was properly configured. As we can see, the calls to that are just fake calls... doing nothing...

**Summary**: do not care about `NoCacheProvider` or `FakeCache`.

*NOTE: On the other hand, properly configure Cache provider not only for Query cache, but you should also turn on the Second Level Cache. These are in fact tightly coupled...*

```
config.Cache(c => c
    .ProviderClass....
      .UseQueryCache()
      .UseSecondLevelCache() // Second Leve Cache keeps items by ID
```

EXTEND:

In case we do not want/like to see any internal features, e.g: [NoCacheProvider.cs](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Cache/NoCacheProvider.cs)

```
namespace NHibernate.Cache
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A cache provider placeholder used when caching is disabled.
    /// </summary>
    public class NoCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
    {
        private static readonly IInternalLogger log = LoggerProvider
            .LoggerFor(typeof(NoCacheProvider));

        public const string WarnMessage = "Second-level cache is enabled in a class,"+
                              " but no cache provider was selected. Fake cache used.";
        ....
```

Just inject our own/custom implementation of the `ICacheProvider` - without any logging etc. That is the biggest power of NHibernate - it is really very extensible and adjustable.

Comment: If it does not do anything, I should not see anything in the log. It fills up the log with more warnings. 09-22 16:43:12,570 WARN  [58] An item was expired by the cache while it was locked (increase your cache timeout): Model - NHibernate.Cache.ReadWriteCache [(null)] . I understand it comes from a top level implementation of Second Level Cache. But it is annoying to see the warning when it is a Null Object Pattern implementation. I want to get rid of annoying logging.

Comment: The biggest power of the NHibernate is in its support of extending, injecting custom implementation. If you really feel that this slows you down, you can implement your Own `ICacheProvider` or `ICache` and inject them into the configuration. Then you can have your own "clear" implementation. But again, null object pattern is there for a reason. It does help to solve/simplify handling if no "real" implementation is used. Does it help?

Comment: Problem is at higher level. Not on the implementation of NoCacheProvider or FakeCache. Disabling the second level cached fixed the whole issue. Thanks for your time. Logs seems to be correct when reviewing the top level implementation.